# Array size as a const in interface- gives error

Tags: objective-c

This class is importing some const variable from other class , and trying to use that as a variable to define array size .

so i have :

```
@interface reciever :NSObject
{
int16_t buffersRing[numOfBuffers+1][1025];
```

**error :** instance variable must have a constant size .

but `numOfBuffers` is a global const from other class :

```
extern const int numOfBuffers ;
```

so , how can i use the const to define my array size ?

Answer (score 0):

Just because a variable is declared `const` doesn't mean it's constant.  It just means it's read only.  You need a *compile-time* constant to define an array size.

Comment: thank you,what is the solution ? i want to use that variable from the imported file, what are my ways ? define it where ?

Comment: You can't use a variable at all, unless you switch to using runtime/dynamic allocation for this array.

Comment: thanks but i could not understand you answer, its not clear to me enough, so i will wait for another answer with some more details .

Comment: What kind of details do you want?  If you want `buffersRing` to be sized at compile-time, you need to use `#define` or some other kind of compile-time constant.  If you want to use `numOfBuffers`, you need to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: for example a line of code that shows me how can i use that variable- that i must use- and use it some how to define the size of the array?

Comment: And btw , you wrong, i could define them in that way just before, when i set them to be as a const in some other .h file , now i am working with .m and .h files with extern values and it does not work anymore .